# Custom camera app but unable to create a folder to store the image

Tags: android

I want to create a folder to store the captured image. From this, the image is taken however, the file directory is not created, and once I tilt the device, the image will be permanently gone. How should I proceed on? I have looked for many examples online and thus derived with such solution. I'm new to android platform but I'm learning. Any help is appreciated! Thanks =)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);             
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);    
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"imageView");
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
    }

}

static public boolean hasStorage(boolean requireWriteAccess) {
    //TODO: After fix the bug,  add "if (VERBOSE)" before logging errors.
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        if (requireWriteAccess) {
            boolean writable = checkFsWritable();
            return writable;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else if (!requireWriteAccess && Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

}

```
private static boolean checkFsWritable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code

```
photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, "/AudioRecorder/" + image.jpg);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(file ));
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

and add this to your code after onCreate

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this out, however, after i took a photo, it wouldn't allow me to press the "tick". so I can't accept the photo to see it it work. any idea to why is it so?

Comment: i have updated my code please use it and let me know if you still have any problem... And if it works then accept and upvote the answer. Thank you

Comment: hey, sorry if this is a stupid question, but what is the intent i for actually? why do i need a new activity class and that the camera still does not accept the tick.

Comment: it will allow you to move to next activity. When you press "tick" button then above code will allow you to go to another activity. and your image will be stored in your SDCard's with folder name AudioRecorder

Comment: so i just leave the activity class 2 empty?

Comment: No you can do whatever logic you want to put no need to put empty screen, either you can get the captured image in second activity or other then this you can also use your logic in this activity also but this is just sample example.

Comment: tyvm for your help! =)

Answer (score 3):

If you still need to access the SD card, the Camera application  that checks if the SD card is mounted as follows:

```
    static public boolean hasStorage(boolean requireWriteAccess) {
        //TODO: After fix the bug,  add "if (VERBOSE)" before logging errors.
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        Log.v(TAG, "storage state is " + state);

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            if (requireWriteAccess) {
                boolean writable = checkFsWritable();
                Log.v(TAG, "storage writable is " + writable);
                return writable;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (!requireWriteAccess && Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        r

eturn false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not really sure on what is happening in these codes as i'm still learning. Like LOG.v, TAG and stuff. what are they actually?

Comment: print output in logcat  . user it :: Log.v("storage writable is ",  writable);

Comment: I've edited. but it seems like the problem is still the same. would you mind pointing out where did I do wrong? I didn't use logcat to track my codes coz I'm not familar..

Comment: call this hasStorage(true) method 

if(hasStorage(true))
{
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"imageView");
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
}else
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Writeable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}